# What is the difference between "Peak Shaving" and "Curtailment"?

Tags: word-meaning

In the energy domain, I often read "Peak Shaving" and "Curtailment" but I am not sure I understand the difference between the two.

> Peak Shaving refers to leveling out peaks in gas usage for all
> consumers. During high demand, natural gas companies will essentially
> reduce the amount of power consumption at small increments to avoid
> peak loads.
> Curtailment is the act of restricting or reducing supply.
> This is particularly common in the oil and gas industry, which has to
> respond quickly to changes in supply and demand.

https://pipelinepodcastnetwork.com/plpc-episode-224-peak-shaving-curtailment-utility-operations-mary-palkovich/

What I think I've understand is curtailment is a way to perform peak shaving, is that correct?

Comment: While @MichaelHarvey 's comment and answer are probably correct, it should be noted that in the context provided, this is industry jargon, and needs to be understood in that context. In such cases, you are best off asking someone who is involved in the industry in question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in oil and natural gas delivery, but after some research, the difference between the two seems primarily to be one of who is reducing the fuel.

**Curtailment** is done by an oil or gas supplier.  When demand for their product exceeds the delivery capacity of their system (usually a pipeline), the seller cannot keep up with the market's demand.  They must tell some customers that they will receive less product than they want.  Less important customers have their supply reduced in favor of more important customers, in a typical curtailment situation.

The reason for curtailment is that the supplier cannot satisfy all of their customers' demands and so must choose which receive product.  How they respond - proportional cuts to all customers or the more common approach of favoring some customers in place of others - is another question.

**Peak shaving** is done by a consumer, often in concert with an oil or gas supplier.  A major manufacturer or power generation company can store fuel, usually gas, on site.  When there is a peak in demand (perhaps due to weather, geopolitical, or market forces) they can voluntarily reduce their consumption from the oil and gas supplier at the peak of demand.  This can either be done by reducing their activity or by supplementing their delivered fuel supply with fuel that was purchased previously and stored on site.  The fuel could be the same as is supplied normally or it could be something like synthetic natural gas.

The reason for the consumer voluntarily accepting either reduced activity or the additional cost of maintaining their own supply is that oil and gas prices fluctuate with market conditions, so it can be very expensive at the peak times.  By shaving (removing) those peaks, a company can save significant amounts of money by not paying peak prices for fuel.